# Script to append files with same part of the name

Tags: shell, awk

I have a bunch of files (> 1000), which content has columns of numbers separates by space. I would like to reduce the number of files by appending the content of groups of them in one file.

All the files start with `"*time_NUMBER*"` followed by a number, and the rest of the filename `(*pow_....txt*)`. For example : `*time_0.6pow_0.1-173.txt*`

I would like to append the files with the same *NUMBER* in a single file and make it with a script since I got ~70 different NUMBERs.

I have found

```
cat time_0.6pow_*.txt > time_0.6.txt
```

it works but would like to make a script for all the possible NUMBERs.

Regards

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (e.g. 3 or 4 of those files you mention) and the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for fName in time_*pow_*.txt; do
    s="${fName#time_}"
    cat "$fName" >> time_"${s%%pow*}".txt
done
```